# Specflow not working correctly with VS 2012

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2012, specflow

Version of .NET Framework installed: .Net 4

VS 2012 from : www.microsoft.com/.../downloads

I was able to run SpecFlow tests using Visual NUnit in VS 2010 perfectly. I recently installed VS 2012 from the above mentioned site and tried to run the specflow tests. The specflow version is 1.8.1. The problem is the VS 2012 is treating the feature files as text files, the formatting doesn't work, no colors for scenarios etc. Also I cant find the Visual Nunit listed in the View->Other Windows list. Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to repair or uninstall / reinstall SpecFlow.  The reason is that SpecFlow was installed before 2012, and so it did not register itself with 2012.  Alternately you can get the lastest SpecFlow (1.9) from the Extension Manager under the Tools menu.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but it was resolved by changing unitTestProvider to name="MSTest" and make sure "MST is capital letter, then restart the visual studio and set the SpecFlow Test Runner Tool (in Visual Studio Options) to Visual Studio 2012.